# SQL Server function return table slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have an function in SQL Server that return me all appointment time available for an month. The query itself take 3 sec only but my function i don't know why maybe the insert take at least 23 to 30 second to return it. I don't know if you can add up index on a table declare in an function.

Here's my function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RDV_fnGetAvailabilityMonth] 
    (@IdCie Int, @IdBranch Int,
     @IdRessource Int, @ServiceDuration Int,
     @year Int, @month Int)
RETURNS @GetAvailabilityMonth TABLE
   (IdSchedulingByIntervalMin int,
    IdSchedulingByIntervalMax int,
    startHours datetime2,
    endHours datetime2,
    [date] date)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @newInterval int,
            @MinDate datetime2,
            @MaxDate datetime2,
            @RangeDateBegin date,
            @RangeDateEnd date

    set @RangeDateBegin = CAST(CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(4)) +RIGHT('0' + CAST(@month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +RIGHT('0' + CAST('01' AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)AS DATE)
    set @RangeDateEnd  = cast(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@RangeDateBegin)+1,0))as date)
    set @newInterval = (CEILING(cast(@ServiceDuration as float) / cast(5 as float))) * 5

    insert into @GetAvailabilityMonth
        SELECT 
            t1.IdSchedulingByInterval AS IdSchedulingByIntervalMin,
            t2.IdSchedulingByInterval AS IdSchedulingByIntervalMax,
            t1.SchedulingByIntervalStartDate, 
            t2.SchedulingByIntervalEndDate,
            cast(t1.SchedulingByIntervalStartDate as date) as [date]
        FROM   
            RDV_tbSchedulingByInterval t1
        JOIN 
            RDV_tbSchedulingByInterval t2 ON t2.SchedulingByIntervalStartDate = DATEADD(minute, @newinterval - 5, t1.SchedulingByIntervalStartDate) 
                                          AND t1.IdCie = t2.IdCie 
                                          AND t1.IdBranch = t2.IdBranch 
                                          AND t1.IdResource = t2.IdResource
        WHERE
            t1.IdCie = @IdCie AND t1.IdBranch = @IdBranch 
            AND t1.IdResource = @IdRessource 
            AND cast(t1.SchedulingByIntervalStartDate as date) BETWEEN @RangeDateBegin AND @RangeDateEnd
            AND (select SUM(5) from RDV_tbSchedulingByInterval where SchedulingByIntervalReserve = 0 and SchedulingByIntervalIsUnavailable = 0 and  IdSchedulingByInterval between t1.IdSchedulingByInterval  and t2.IdSchedulingByInterval ) = @newinterval 
       ORDER BY
           t1.SchedulingByIntervalStartDate

  select top 1 @MinDate = startHours ,@MaxDate = endHours  from @GetAvailabilityMonth 

  while exists (select top 1 * from @GetAvailabilityMonth where startHours >= dateadd(minute,@newinterval,@MinDate))
  BEGIN
    if @MaxDate is null
    BEGIN
        select top 1 @MinDate = startHours ,@MaxDate = endHours  from @GetAvailabilityMonth where startHours >= dateadd(minute,@newinterval,@MinDate)
    END
        delete @GetAvailabilityMonth where startHours > @MinDate and startHours < @MaxDate
        set @MaxDate = null
  END 
   RETURN
END
```

Comment: Your query calls a function that contains a loop, neither of which do well with the optimizer. It's going to slow things down a lot.

Comment: You could probably speed this up a bit by replacing your loop with `select min(startDate), max(endDate) group by (month?)`, assuming you're just trying to get the total range for that month.

Comment: This is what is known as a multi-statement table valued function. They are routinely far slower than even a scalar valued function. Add to that your looping and you have a performance nightmare on your hands. Also, you have queries using top but no order by so you have no way of knowing which row will be returned. This needs to be completely rewritten as a set based query instead of RBAR.

Comment: Is this a function or a procedure? Are you really just wanting a few values? Can this not be turned into a set-based solution? For example, if this went to a web-solution, you could use the front end to define where the predicate lands and return just a subset. Either way, this seems a lot for a function to solve instead of proper normalization.

Comment: Yeah I just turn this into an procedure alot faster now